# Customizing Document ID in SharePoint Online using a background process

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, document-library, csom, document-id

I'm looking to use a custom formula for generating a document ID in SharePoint online. Each document will have:

- A three letter project code, defined by the "Begin IDs with the following characters" value in the site's Document ID Settings.
- A four digit number, incremented by one for every document.
- A D or EXT to indicate the document type, defined in a SharePoint document library column.

For the document ID, I want to concatenate these properties so that the document ID is `<project code>-<incremental number>-<doc type>`.

My understanding is that if I want to create a custom document ID in SharePoint Online, I need to follow the add-in model for building logic. Based on Microsoft's documentation (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/document-id-provider-sharepoint-add-in), and my use case where I could potentially have bulk document uploads, I would need to use a background process that runs in Azure WebJobs.

I'm having difficulty finding examples of a SharePoint Online Document ID provider being built as a background process. I have been able to build an empty web job using Microsoft's examples, but I can't find any information on how to write the document ID provider logic in this model. Is there any guidance out there that I might be missing? Is it even possible to do what I'm attempting to do? Is there any easier method for customizing document ID generation in SharePoint Online, such as Power Automate?